# Error encountered running: sudo -i gem pristine --all

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The command was run on Fedora 20. 
How do I stop the gem bigdecimal-1.2.0 being fetched as I have 1.2.5 already.

Output

```
Restoring gems to pristine condition...
Restored actionmailer-4.1.1
Restored actionpack-4.1.1
Restored actionview-4.1.1
Restored activemodel-4.1.1
Restored activerecord-4.1.1
Restored activesupport-4.1.1
Restored arel-5.0.1.20140414130214
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Restored bigdecimal-1.2.5
Cached gem for bigdecimal-1.2.0 not found, attempting to fetch...
Fetching: bigdecimal-1.2.0.gem (100%)
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::InstallError)
    invalid gem: No such file or directory - /usr/share/gems/cache/bigdecimal-1.2.0.gem
```

Comment: sudo -i gem uninstall bigdecimal 1.2.0
Successfully uninstalled bigdecimal-1.2.5 - didn't work

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
sudo -i gem uninstall -i /usr/share/gems bigdecimal
Successfully uninstalled bigdecimal-1.2.0
```

Rerunning

```
sudo -i gem pristine --all
```

I no longer get the error.

Answer (score 1):

In my case there was the following problem with `gem pristine --all` (w/o sudo).

`gem uninstall bigdecimal` didn't work.
`gem uninstall -i ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@global bigdecimal` helped.