# Uninstall non-existing Ruby gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, spring-gem

When starting Ruby on Rails WEBrick server (Ubuntu 14.04) the following message appears: "Warning: You're using Rubygems 1.8.23 with Spring. Upgrade to at least Rubygems 2.1.0 and run `gem pristine --all` for better startup performance."

I've upgraded Rubygems and ran `gem pristine --all`, but it seems to have trouble with the `thor` gem. The reason is I have the following installed `thor` gem versions (according to `gem list` command):

> thor (0.19.1, 0.18.1.20140116)

and there is NO 'thor' gem version 0.18.1.20140116 anywhere. I can't uninstall it and I can't install it. If I install and uninstall 0.18.1 version, it doesn't affect 0.18.1.20140116 version at all.

So `gem pristine --all` command stops when checking `thor` with the following error:

> Restored thor-0.19.1
>   Cached gem for thor-0.18.1.20140116 not found, attempting to fetch...
>   ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::Exception)
>       Cannot load gem at [/usr/share/rubygems-integration/1.9.1/cache/thor-0.18.1.20140116.gem] in /home/****/******/*********

How can I remove that funny 0.18.1.20140116 version from system or make `gem pristine` not to check the `thor` gem?

Thank you!

Comment: what does `gem which thor` returns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved that problem by deleting

> /usr/share/rubygems-integration/1.9.1/specifications/thor-0.8.1.20140116.gemspec

manually with root rights.

Thank you guys for help!

Answer (score 0):

Was there any error message when you uninstall "thor 0.18.1.20140116"?

I wonder if it helps to uninstall all versions of thor and reinstall 0.19.1.

```
gem uninstall thor # Select "All versions" here
gem install thor -v 0.19.1
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `thor (0.18.1.20140116)` string remains in the result of the `gem list` command after `gem uninstall thor`. And when I try to remove this particular version it throws `INFO:  gem "thor" is not installed` error. The problem is in that `20140116`.

Comment: Umm... Have you seen this post? 

It feels similar: [Error encountered running: sudo -i gem pristine --all](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23759717)

Also this [GitHub thread](https://github.com/rails/spring/issues/320)